# Find value of row in gridview selected by context menu over it in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I bound a `GridView` to `DataTable` values. I wrote a context menu using jQuery. My question is how to read the contents of the row on which I right click my context menu.

Example -   to find the number of rows in grid view I used `$("#<%=gridview1. ClientID%> tr").length`, which works nicely.

How do I read any cell or row of grid view when I only have grid view ID (GridView1)?

```
Gridview1.datasource=dt
Gridview1.databind ()
```

jQuery

```
$('#grid').bind ("contextmenu",function       (e){
e.preventDefault ();
......
var $v=$("#<%=gridview1. ClientID%>    tr").length;
$("#divdisplay").html (v)
});
```

Comment: Can you add additional code examples,  including the JavaScript that produces the context menu, to give enough information for people to figure out what is happening?

Comment: Hi . I have edited my question with some code. I just want to read the row values on which I click in jquery. I have gridview1 as gridview id. Like I found out number of rows using line I wrote in var v. I want to fetch any value of that row. Please help. :((

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
$('#grid').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    e.preventDefault ();

    var clickedCellText = $(e.target).text(); // clicked cell text
    var firstCellText = $(e.target).parent().find(':first-child').text(); // first cell text

    //...your code
});
```

Comment: Hi . I have edited my question with some code. I just want to read the row values on which I click in jquery. I have gridview1 as gridview id. Like I found out number of rows using line I wrote in var v. I want to fetch any value of that row. Please help. :((

Comment: @user3228318: try with `$(e.target).text()`. `e.target` should be the cell (td) where you clicked but not the row (tr).

Comment: @user3228318: could you please add `alert(e.target.tagName)`?

Comment: @user3228318: it means that you're on the correct element... why is `text()` not giving you what you expect? Aren't you trying to get content of cell?

Comment: I want to get the content of the cell exactly . If I write ->  $(e.target).Text() . It does not show anything in my div. When I write the same line in alert ->  alert ($(e.target).Text) it gives "undefined" in alert

Comment: Or if you can tell me how to grab 1st cell of the selected row. Anything would do my work !

Comment: if `alert($(e.target).text())` shows nothing it means you clicked on a cell with no content. I'm a litthe confused with your test result.

Comment: It worked . Text didn't work. It was 'text ()' ,Thanks a ton . :) can I also ask one thing . How to grab only first cell value irrespective of his click in any cell in the row

Comment: @user3228318: updated my answer to reflect your real question(s)